# sound card makes mouth popping noise

Tags: sound-card

sound card makes mouth popping noise...

Hard to describe the sound, but it's the sound you make when you roll the tongue and brush it against the palate (roof of your mouth).

I have set system sound scheme to none.

Realtek High Definition Audio. Everest tells me that the model number is ALC887.

This is the driver installed: 6.0.1.6141

It's Windows 7.

Edit: it's not the "tsk" sound!

Edit: **Dell XPS 8300 desktop - i7 - h67 motherboard** - do you need more information?

Comment: every second? every 5 seconds? all the time? when you plug something in? when music starts?

Comment: I really tried to figure out the pattern, but I could not... it's definitely not every second. It seems random more than anything. It's like if I click a menu, it will make that sound. If I click that menu again, no sound. If I don't click anything, yet it'll make the sound...

Comment: Some of these issues are specific to Make and Model of PC, please edit your original post to include this information.